# How do I write some text using Selenium/Python in this html

Tags: python, selenium, text, insert, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to insert some text in the following field but it says it is not interactable

```
<div class="col-md-6">
<div id="tagsReview" class="p4-autocomplete" style="width: 179px; border-radius: 4px;">
<ul class="p4-autocomplete-labels"></ul><input type="text"><ul class="p4-autocomplete-suggestions" style="width: 179px; display: none;">
<li class="newItem selected"><a>Criar novo marcador</a></li>
</div>
```

I tried different approaches but none of them worked.

Any ideas? Tks!

EDIT:

This code works to click in the text field:
`driver.find_element_by_id('tagsReview').click()`

Send keys to that Id does not work:

```
driver.find_element_by_id('tagsReview').send_keys('xyz')
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.61)
```

Other attempts:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//*[contains(@class,'p4-autocomplete')])").send_keys('xyz')
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.61)

driver.find_element_by_class_name('p4-autocomplete-labels').click()
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.61)

driver.find_element_by_class_name('p4-autocomplete').click()
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <div id="tagsSearch" class="p4-autocomplete" style="float: right; margin-top: -5px; width: 179px;">...</div> is not clickable at point (1254, 224). Other element would receive the click: <div id="dlgCreateNextReview" class="modal in" tabindex="-1" style="display: block;">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.61)
```

Comment: Add the code you have tried.

Comment: Ok, Done @Jortega

Comment: `send_keys` will add text to a text field, are you trying to add text to a text field?

Comment: yes.. but I just solved with driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='tagsReview']/input")

Answer (score 0):

`send_keys` works for input-fields : Since you have tried for `div` text-appending it doesn't work that way.

You could try this (uses javascript):

```
driver.execute_script("document.querySelector('#tagsReview').innerText = 'XYZ';")
```

Answer (score 0):

I just solved with driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='tagsReview']/input")